# edit data in pane result

Tags: sql, sql-server, pane, isqlquery

I have run a query through pane in sql server 2008. Now I want to change some data from the result, but it shows error, "No row was updated. The data in row 2 was not committed".

How can I change data in pane result.

Comment: sounds like you can't change the date because it would violate a unique index or primary key. Otherwise the updates would work though the pannel...

Comment: then what is the solution?

Comment: Well, confirm that is its a unique index/ primary key violation. and if it is adjust your data so that you're no longer violating a unique index or key, or drop the index/key. (but be careful about dropping those!)